# How do I properly specify dependencies in a published Android library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm creating an Android library that will be published to something like Sonatype. Some of my classes depend on classes in the AppCompat library.

If my Android module look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
}
```

will my users run into problems if they add my library as a dependency and also add some future version of `appcompat` as a dependency?

And related, is there a way I can set this up so they don't have to specify transitive dependencies, or would that even be expected for ease of use?

Comment: User can exclude like this: compile('you.library', {exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  })